# How much electricity does it take to polarize specific types of insulators?

Tags: electrical-engineering, experimental-physics, chemistry

as I hope you know, electric polarization is when you put an insulator in an electric field, and the nucleus and electron cloud go in an opposite direction. https://www.priyamstudycentre.com/2020/02/electric-polarization.html

I was wondering how much electricity do you need to polarize a molecule? Is there an equation? If there is it would be great if you could explain it to me as I'm new to this. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: As that site indicates, this is more a physics or chemistry question.

Comment: Should I just use Columb's law?

Comment: I would think *any* amount of electric field can cause it.